# British English for possessive 's when a names ends with "s"

Tags: british-english, possessives

My son has a teacher that he wishes to give a gift to, Mrs. Coomes.

What is the correct way to use what would normally be `'s` when the name ends with `es`? Another answer states adding `es` on the end however "Mrs. Coomeses buscuit tin" "feels" wrong.

Comment: One would never **spell** a possessive as "Coomeses", although one might **say** that. See the nominated duplicate.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you @AndrewLeach, exactly what I was after.